# Why the make command complain about the cmake version while I have already updated cmake version?

Tags: cmake

I am using a repo requiring at least cmake 3.12. I had cmake 3.10.2, So I updated it to cmake 3.17.0. Now when I run `cmake --version`, I get `cmake version 3.17.0` following [How to reinstall the latest cmake version?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689105/1729252)
. But, when I use the repo, I still get the following error

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_minimum_required):
   CMake 3.12 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.10.2
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Did you delete your CMake cache, and re-run CMake from scratch within the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem! But, I removed `cmake` and used https://apt.kitware.com/ before installing `cmake-3.17.0` and the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Consider your are building out or source, remove everything, and run cmake again (configure step). If you've set the PATH in your environment correctly, your problem should be fixed.